# How to delete a mysql record with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, sql-delete

I have this following code that delete a mysql record and I would like to transform it so It would be a ajax/jquery code so I can stay in the same page after the record has been deleted from the table.
Now, it working fine but it not on the same page and I need to refresh the page to see the result.  This is only a part of the full code.
All the code in on one page.

```
//get the mysql results
//this is a repeated region
<tr>
       <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
       <td><a href="manage.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
       </td>
</tr>


if ((isset($_GET['deleteid'])) && ($_GET['deleteid'] != "") &&             (isset($_POST['delete']))) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['deleteid'], "int"));
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague for Stack Overflow and you can't really expect people to write code for you. If you have a specific question or error, you'll be more likely to get some quality answers.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I noticed that your code doesn't appear to have any sort of CSRF protection. I hope that was omitted from your sample code just for sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<tr>
       <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
       <td><div class="delete_class" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</div></td>
</tr>
```

Now in the  section write this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".delete_class").click(function(){
   var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'delete_page.php',
      data:'delete_id='+del_id,
      success:function(data) {
        if(data) {   // DO SOMETHING
        } else { // DO SOMETHING }
      }
   });
 });
});
```

Now in the 'delete_page.php' page do this

```
$id = $_POST['delete_id'];
$query = "delete from TABLE NAME where ID = $id";
```

Rest I hope you know. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the script!  That helped a lot.  I think that I need to learn more about jquery so I can use it more often.  But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery and something like this will do the trick

```
<tr>
       <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
       <td><a href="#" onClick="delete (<?php echo $row['id']; ?>); return false;">Delete</a>
       </td>
</tr>

<script>
function delete(id){
  $.post("manage.php", { deleteid: id , delete: true} );
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the script, but that not working for me.  When I click delete, nothing happens.  I dont know why.

Comment: @user1932820 do you have jQuery?