# run php on html link click and stay on same page after refresh

Tags: php, html

I have a table of data that I want to allow users to remove rows from by clicking a link in the table. I'm looking to have the page refresh and the row that the user selects removed from the table. This is done based on calling a php function which alters the table's database. What I have so far is

```
<tr>
    <td width = '35%'><?php echo $the_title?></td>
    <td width = '20%'><?php echo $val1?></td>
    <td width = '10%'><?php echo $val2 ?></td>
    <td width = '15%'><a href='?remove_now=<?php echo $row?>' name=''>Remove Now</a></td>
</tr>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['remove_now'])){
    $row_to_remove=$_GET['remove_now'];
    my_func ($row_to_remove);}

?>
```

When I click the Remove Now link it changes the page, because I'm already on a hashed page, which I don't want it to do. It also doesn't run my_func. 
Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Check this case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106568/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-with-jquery-ajax-php close to yours ;)

Comment: @evan.stoddard I'm fine using whatever, but at the end of the day I need/want to call a php function to remove the entry from the database

Comment: @bob_hardy use ajax to call a php file that will call your function.

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the server side, where a page update runs on the client (browser). If you want to execute php code, either the page has to be refreshed, or you need to use a javascript ajax call that will actually access the "page" on the server you're looking for, grab its data, and make it available to the current page (that made the ajax call).

If you just want to manipulate the page and don't need any data from the server, just use javascript. Javascript is for dom manipulation, not php.

Comment: the page should refresh when the link is clicked. I don't just want to change what's on the page, I want to change what's in the table database.

Comment: @bob_hardy you REALLY need to study web development basics. That's all I can say. This is an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot do what you are trying to do with php.  You need to use javascript to do what you want.

Here are some ways you can accomplish what you want

1) use javascript to manipulate the table that is already rendered on your page

or

2) use php to render the table without the desired row when the page initially loads

if you need to use php as part of the row removal process, you should look into ajax.

based on you comment, try something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td width = '35%'><?php echo $the_title?></td>
    <td width = '20%'><?php echo $val1?></td>
    <td width = '10%'><?php echo $val2 ?></td>
<?php
$maxnumrows = 10;
for($i=0;$i<$maxnumrows;$i++){
    if (    (!isset($_GET['remove_now'])) || ( (isset($_GET['remove_now'])) && ($_GET['remove_now']!=$i) ) ){
        ?>
        <td width = '15%'><a href='?remove_now='<?php echo $i?> name=''>Remove Now</a>  </td>
<?php
    }
}
?>    

</tr>
```

Comment: the page should refresh when the link is click, so I'm pretty sure I can run php in this way.

Comment: wouldn't that just remove the "remove now" link from the table? I want each row to have a "remove now" link when it's in the table and clicking the link removes the entire row. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @bob_hardy yes it would.  i modified the code so you can easily see how you can duplicate the code to work on multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Closing quote on href attribute is wrong. It should be after closing php tag like this.

`<td width = '15%'><a href='?remove_now=<?php echo $row?>' name=''>Remove Now</a></td>`

And yes .. javascript and ajax will work as well as just clicking the link and display same page. If you don't want url to be changed put `header("Location ....")` after my_func call

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to delete entries from the database, and you're just thinking a little backwards. Here's a simplified piece of logic that may help you understand how to go about this:

```
// See if they just deleted something
// If so we will delete the data and reload the page
if(isset($_GET['delete_id']))){
  // Run the code that deletes the entry from the database
  deleteFromDatabase($_GET['delete_id']);
  // Now that we've done that just cleanly reload the page
  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // This refers to the current page without the $_GET query string - there must not be any page output before you call this
  die(); // Always kill the script after reloading the location header
}

// Here's your normal output (whatever you would normally do for output)
getTableData();
outputTable();
echo '<table>Whatever etc...';
?>
```

Comment: I think I'm following but whatever I'm doing doesn't seem to be satisfying the 'if statement' in order to run the php function. Could you add in what the link html would look like? Thank you!

Comment: href="page.php?delete_id=4" should do the trick. That would submit the value of 4 to your delete function. Don't forget to validate this value since a user can put anything in the url.

Comment: Oops, there was a typo as well. Changed $GET to $_GET