# Form action not allowing the delete of a record

Tags: php, mysql

I had to add a `form` action to go to a different page to edit a specific record, but with doing that, it won't allow me to delete a record because it is taking me away from it before it will do the `query`. I am unsure of how to make this work and still get to the new page when I hit the "Edit" button.

```
<table id="tableid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Save</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php
        $stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT `id`,`first`,`last`,`product` FROM users");
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="edit-product">
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?>"</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['first'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['last'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['product'];?></td>
                <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" readonly>
                <input name="first" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['first'];?>">
                <input name="last" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['last'];?>">
                <input name="product" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['product'];?>">
                <td><input name="save" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
                <td><div class="delete-class" name="delete" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</div></td>
                <td><input name="edit" type="submit" value="Edit"></td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

PHP `DELETE` `query`

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

How can I change the markup to still get both the edit (going to another page with the action) and the delete to work on this page?

UPDATE AJAX code:

```
$(function() {

    $(".delete_class").click(function(){
   var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'delete-product.php',
      data:'delete_id='+del_id,
      success:function(data) {
        if(data) {   // DO SOMETHING
        } else { // DO SOMETHING }
      }
)); //here
 });

});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `action="edit-product.php"` in place of `action="edit-product"` ?

Comment: The action works. The issue is the action doesn't allow my delete query to work. I want to stay on the same page for the delete query.

Comment: Also, the way you have set your form, the system would possibly NOT know which row to delete. You should probably turn your `id` column into a radio button or a checkbox.

Comment: Then you should make the form submit to itself and add the form processing code to the main page itself.

Comment: The delete query worked fine for the specific record before I added the action. I only added the action to make the edit work for that specific record.

Comment: Is that all the code that you have or is there more ? Do you have multiple rows in your form or a single row ?

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($_POST)` on your `edit-product` page and see what is the data that you are actually getting via POST ?

Comment: I just added more HTML.

Comment: I'm getting all of the correct information to the edit page. The issue is with the delete. It won't process because it takes me to the different page.

Comment: Looks like your code is generating multiple forms here since the form generation code is inside the while loop. What you should probably do is move the while loop inside your form tag that way you have only one form.

Comment: Only one form is displaying, though?

Comment: I am not entirely sure if that is the case, looking at the code that you posted. What do you mean by delete takes you to a different page ?

Comment: When I click the delete button `<td><input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete"></td>`, since the action of the form is to take the user to `edit-product` the delete query never runs. I don't want to go to `edit-product` when I hit the delete button. I want it to stay on the same page, but I need the action to be `action="edit-product" to allow the Edit button to take me there.

Comment: I think in this case, you might be better off using AJAX. Something like this maybe: https://davidwalsh.name/demo/jquery-record-delete.php . Else, you might have to create a form corresponding to each button taking you to different pages based on the action selected (Save/Edit/Delete)

Comment: It worked before the action though? There isn't anyway to do this with reformatting the html somehow to avoid the action sending me elsewhere?

Comment: On what page is `PHP DELETE query` code located ?

Comment: The page with the html that I showed you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very ideal but one way to do it. You change the HTML markup to create two forms, one for edit case and another one for Delete. The delete case sends the request to the current page like this:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['first'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['last'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['product'];?></td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="edit-product">
                <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
                <input name="first" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['first'];?>">
                <input name="last" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['last'];?>">
                <input name="product" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['product'];?>">
                <input name="save" type="submit" value="Edit">
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">   
                <input name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } 
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
// the delete code goes here
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

I left out the save case but it will be similar to edit case.

Comment: I am fine with using ajax. I just want the edit to go to the page I have in the action and then the delete to stay on the current page and delete the record. That is all.

Comment: Well, eventually I was wanting to do AJAX for this anyways, so could I do it with AJAX the way I had it without going to the action place? Would an `event.preventDefault` work for that?

Comment: You would need to write additional jQuery/JS code and add new PHP files if you want to go with the AJAX option. You would possibly need to change the HTML markup as well. I don't think `event.preventDefault` will by itself do nothing. Look at one on the AJAX examples I posted in the comments or go through some basic PHP/jQuery/AJAX tutorials.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106568/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-with-jquery if you want to take the AJAX route.

Comment: Okay, so I am trying to do the ajax method from this link in your last comment. The way they have the delete within the html table doesn't make sense. It just says the word "DELETE". Should I make it a link or what? `<td><div class="delete-class" name="delete" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</div></td>`

Comment: No. With AJAX it works differently. You don't need to make it a link but AJAX "binds" the action to a click event if that makes sense. Again, I would start with a basic PHP/jQuery/AJAX tutorial.

Comment: I would also recommend to get the non-AJAX version working first and then switch to AJAX.

Comment: I know how to use AJAX. I have a syntax error and that is why. An unexpected token that is driving me nuts. I cannot figure out the issue. I edited my answer with the ajax code.

Comment: I think you should create a new question for AJAX case. After taking a quick look at your AJAX code, I see that you don't have `delete_class` specified anywhere in your markup so the AJAX request won't even go through.

Comment: `<td><div class="delete-class" name="delete" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</div></td>`

Comment: Can you update your question with the corresponding changes to the HTML markup that you made for the AJAX case ?

Comment: The html changes was just for the delete button, nut I updated the code in the question. I am just getting an unexpected token for the closing brackets of the ajax. I cannot figure out which ones to delete, add or modify. I have tried it 10 different ways.

Comment: Looks like you have `class="delete-class"` in the markup but `$(".delete_class")` in the AJAX code. Could this be the issue. Additionally, you can use Firebug or other web developer browser plugins to track the AJAX request/response. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412353/how-to-find-whether-ajax-request-successfully-send-by-fire-bug-add-on

Comment: I'm using the chrome console. I just don't see what is wrong. Thanks for catching the wrong class name. That didn't help though. It is saying the error is here" `} else { // DO SOMETHING }
      }
)); //here
 });

});`

Comment: I edited my question to show where the error was coming from to make it easier to see.

Comment: Looks like your AJAX code is not doing anything if the request was successful. Ideally, you want to update the div/span with the returned data so that it gives the user an impression that the update was made without them leaving the page.

Comment: It is stopping the code from even doing anything because of the error. This might be the easiest way to show you. http://www.optimumwebdesigns.com/pdo-products

Comment: If you are using AJAX, then you need to get rid of the `<form>` tag completely. AJAX will take care of that part. The form submission logic won't even let your AJAX request through.

Comment: Possibly. I mean when I tested it in my browser, the AJAX part was not even getting triggered.

Comment: @maximum Well, how can I trigger it without a form?

Comment: Start by removing all the form tags from that page and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a form you could just have links instead of form submit buttons. That way each link could take you to a specific page that performs a specific task. By passing query string variables and using $_GET rather than $_POST, you can retain the product ID information.

Example:

```
<td><a href="save_product.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Save</a></td>
<td><a href="delete_product.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</a></td>
<td><a href="edit_product.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Edit</a></td>
```

These individual pages could then perform your tasks in the database. Both save and delete could use Header re-directs to get back to your original page with your product list.

delete_product.php Example:

```
// delete product from database
    $id = $_GET['id']; // Note that it's a $_GET
    $stmt = $dbc->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();

// re-direct to original list page
    header("Location: product_list.php"); // or whatever you have your list page named.
```

The edit_product.php page would then have your typical form for making changes to a specific product. You will need to lookup the product again in the database using $_GET['id'] value to match it with.

As it was suggested in the comments, using AJAX would make the whole process appear to be seamless, rather than jumping around between pages and being re-directed.

Comment: I am fine with using ajax. I just want the edit to go to the page I have in the action and then the delete to stay on the current page and delete the record. That is all.

Comment: Sure. That's what the re-direct is for. It will bring you back to the same page, appearing as if you never left.

Comment: @Maximus2012 is right, you'll need to create these separate files in order to go the AJAX route. My solution sets you up for that future AJAX implementation. As it stands, from my understanding, you're really only using the form as a means of navigation and not actually changing any data in your current setup.