# How to pass value of a corresponding id to a function on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of names displayed separately in individual div sections. Each div section has a button to delete the particular div and delete the corresponding name from the database using an id value. I wanted to delete the name from the database using an id value, So I wanted to pass the corresponding id value to a function. Can anyone please help me on this?

```
<div class='pad pen col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 pern alert' id='bloc_style'>
    <div class='pad col-xs-12 col-md-6'>
        <h4 class='fullname'></h4>
    </div>
    <div class='pad col-md-5'>
        <span class='next-step'>
            <button class='ret_but butt label label-primary' id='equipment' name='equipment' type='button'>Select Equipment</button>
        </span>
        <div class='status'>
            <b>Status</b>
            <i class='open' id='open'>Open</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='pad col-md-1'>
        <button aria-hidden='true' data-dismiss='alert' class='closee' id='deltrash' type='button' OnClick='display(personid);'> 
            <i class='fa fa-trash-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
function display(el) {
    var id = el;
    alert(id);
}
```

The individual ids are stored in the variable `personid`. I want to pass the corresponding `personid` to the function and using that value of `personid` I wanted to delete it from the database. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106568/how-to-delete-a-mysql-record-with-jquery

Comment: @annasujith, You need to show How are you using the _group of names and person Identifiers_ to render HTML. What do expect to read you mind ?(Sorry to be rude)

Comment: Somebody knows, and I think I know, but are you using Javascript / jQuery to communicate with the server side?

Comment: @Nikhil. I want to send the value stored in javascript variable to the jquery on button click..i have generated a code for calculating the personid like this : var pid = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
  
  var str = "PERSONS";
  
  var personid = str.concat(pid);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Your html will be

```
<button aria-hidden='true' data-dismiss='alert' class='closee' id='deltrash' type='button' personid="1" OnClick='display(this);'>
```

And your jquery will be

```
function display(me) {
    id = $(me).attr('personid');
}
```

Comment: i have got the [erson id value using random in javascript like this : var pid = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
  
  var str = "PERSONS";
  
  var personid = str.concat(pid); I want this value to be send to jquery.

Comment: To set the person id to the button $('#deltrash').attr('personid', personid);

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

Set

```
 <button aria-hidden='true' data-dismiss='alert' data-myval="personid" class='closee' id='deltrash' type='button' OnClick='display(this.id);'>
```

JS

```
function display(id) {
    var a = $('#id').data('myval'); //getter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

**Set**

```
 <button aria-hidden='true' data-dismiss='alert' data-myval="personid" class='closee' id='deltrash' type='button' OnClick='display(this);'>
```

JS

```
function display(obj) {
    var a = obj.data('myval'); // change here
}
```